# How to insert current_timestamp into Postgres via python

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

I need to insert rows into PG one of the fields is date and time with time stamp, this is the time of incident, so I can not use --> current_timestamp function of Postgres at the time of insertion, so how can I then insert the time and date which I collected before into pg row in the same format as it would have been created by current_timestamp at that point in time.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A timestamp does not have "a format".

The recommended way to deal with timestamps is to use a PreparedStatement where you just pass a placeholder in the SQL and pass a "real" object through the API of your programming language. As I don't know Python, I don't know if it supports PreparedStatements and how the syntax for that would be.

If you want to put a timestamp literal into your generated SQL, you will need to follow some formatting rules when specifying the value (a literal does have a format).

Ivan's method will work, although I'm not 100% sure if it depends on the configuration of the PostgreSQL server.

A configuration (and language) independent solution to specify a timestamp literal is the ANSI SQL standard:

```
 INSERT INTO some_table 
 (ts_column) 
 VALUES 
 (TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38');
```

Yes, that's the keyword `TIMESTAMP` followed by a timestamp formatted in ISO style (the `TIMESTAMP` keyword defines that format)

The other solution would be to use the `to_timestamp()` function where you can specify the format of the input literal.

```
 INSERT INTO some_table 
 (ts_column) 
 VALUES 
 (to_timestamp('16-05-2011 15:36:38', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: thanks this ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); is working for me.

Comment: You can also use `ms` in to_timestamp to save time millisecond precise.

Comment: Thanks! Using `TIMESTAMP` saved me a whole bunch of time from having to append timezones in Python to all of my datetime values.

Answer (score 88):

If you use [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/index.html) (and possibly some other client library), you can simply pass a Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object as a [parameter](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to a SQL-query:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (%s)', (dt,))
```

(This assumes that the `timestamp with time zone` type is used on the database side.)

More Python types that can be adapted into SQL (and returned as Python objects when a query is executed) are listed [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation).

Comment: datetime.now() is sufficient!

Comment: @Kiro777: Not at all. That would give you a naive datetime object not containing enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other datetime objects. The UTC timezone in the code sample is just an example.

Answer (score 13):

Just use 'now'

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: `now` is exactly the same as `current_timestamp`

Comment: Exactly the same, except that it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked how to do this *via Python*.

Comment: @eugeney You're right. But it seems that some people found it helpful nevertheless. That's why I kept the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

> Date and time input is accepted in almost any reasonable format,
>   including ISO 8601, SQL-compatible, traditional POSTGRES, and others.
>   For some formats, ordering of month, day, and year in date input is
>   ambiguous and there is support for specifying the expected ordering of
>   these fields.

In other words: just write anything and it will work.

Or check [this table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) with all the unambiguous formats.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just pass a string value for that timestamp column in the format: `'2011-05-16 15:36:38'` (you can also append a timezone there, like `'PST'`). PostgreSQL will automatically convert the string to a timestamp. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

then use this in your code:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_table (dt_col) VALUES (%s)', (dt.now(),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` for `datetime` objectives:

```
x.strftime(r'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The main idea here to transform the the `datetime` into a Postgres `timestamp without timezone`, which should be a string when insert.

Answer (score -4):

Just use

> now()

or

> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I prefer the latter as I like not having additional parenthesis but thats just personal preference.

Comment: The question specifically states, "I can not use --> current_timestamp function of Postgres at the time of insertion".